# No cv2.convexityDefects in python opencv ?(ubuntu 12.04)

Tags: python, ubuntu, opencv

As I try to catch convexity  defects in an image with opencv+python, but "python said":

```
    defects = cv2.convexityDefects(cnt,hull)
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'convexityDefects'
```

The python script was running under ubuntu 12.04+python 2.7+opencv from repository.
The code was modified from http://opencvpython.blogspot.fr/2012/06/contours-4-ultimate.html

thanks for your help

jean-pat

Comment: there's cv2.cv.ConvexityDefects but it requires three arg...

Comment: opencv 2.4 must be installed probably whereas only opencv 2.3 is available from ubuntu repository

Comment: after having installed opencv 2.4.2, the problem is solved http://bit.ly/P5xTqQ