# cv2.convexityDefects error

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu

I'm having problems using `convexityDevects`. I get the error: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute convexityDefects`

Have you used efficiently this command?

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('star.jpg')
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(img_gray, 127, 255,0)
contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,2,1)
cnt = contours[0]

hull = cv2.convexHull(cnt,returnPoints = False)
defects = cv2.convexityDefects(cnt,hull)
cv2.imshow('img',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/11332172/2302759

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 12.04 is shipped with outdated OpenCV 2.3.1-7 (http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/python-opencv) and `cv2.convexityDefects` is available since OpenCV 2.4.

You can use `cv.ConvexityDefects` instead. From [official docs](http://docs.opencv.org/2.3/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=convexitydefects#convexitydefects):

> cv.ConvexityDefects(contour, convexhull, storage) → convexityDefects
>      Parameters:
>
> ```
>    contour – Input contour.
>    convexhull – Convex hull obtained using ConvexHull2() that should contain
>                 pointers or indices to the contour points, not the hull points
>                 themselves (the returnPoints parameter in ConvexHull2() should
>                 be zero).
>    storage – Container for the output sequence of convexity defects.
>              If it is NULL, the contour or hull (in that order)
>              storage is used.
> ```
>
> The function finds all convexity defects of the input contour and returns a sequence
>   of the CvConvexityDefect structures, where CvConvexityDetect is defined as:

Comment: Hi, I have the 2.4.6.1 version in my ubuntu 12.04, but i think i will have to use the functions from the old opencv version as you show me in your response. Thanks

Comment: but if someone have ubuntu and opencv 2.4.6, please try my code so you can tell me if it works